# Why can't java find my file?

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to see how many of these text files exist, but even with them there, the program always says the numFiles = 0. I have the files in a folder called Levels within the src folder. Thanks

```
    int numFiles = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
        File file = new File("/Levels/level" + (i+1) + ".txt");
        if(file.exists()){
            numFiles++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(numFiles);
```

Comment: This is a path relative to the system root. Are your src files really located there?

Comment: Please go where your files are located and run `pwd` and `ls -l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

I overlooked that `DirectoryStream`  doesn't support `count()`

You could go with an absolute path and make use of Stream API and lambdas. Like so:

```
String dirString = "..." //absolute Path
Path dir = Paths.get(dirString);

int numFiles = dir.getNameCount();
System.out.println(numFiles);
```

One advantage is that you can rename the files at will as long as they stay in the same directory. If you only want to work with specific files you can use [filter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) like so: 
    `Files.newDirectoryStream(dir).filter(Predicate);`

or add the filter directly when creating the `DirectoryStream` like so:
    `Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, RegEx);`

To do something with each File you can use the consumer [forEach()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) or have a look at [Stream JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for other consumers/intermediate operations. Also double check if the `DirectoryStream` supports the `Stream` operation you want to use.

Comment: where does the fileDir come from?

Comment: Ooops sorry that was a typo. The variable was called fileString before but dirString is a better name. The variable dirString should be a String with the absolute Path to the Directory. And another typo lol should be dir obviously :D

Comment: Oh and by the way instead of count() you can also use forEach(path -> {}); and put the stuff you want to do for each file into the curly braces. You could for example check if a file exists with path.toFile().exists(). Basically the variable path is like an iterator<Path> over all files in the directory.

Comment: it does throw an error however with the .count(). It says that isn't a valid method.

Comment: I just tried dir.getNameCount() and that actually seems to work instead of the Files.newDirectorySteam...

Comment: Oops I thought the DirectoryStream would support all features of the Stream API but I guess some are not supported which is strange. Glad I could still help you and will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect - if you are referring to an absolute location only then start with a /.

Also if you are using an editor remember your Java files are in src but but you don't run Java File you run class files and the class files may be in your bin/build directory most likely - check if the text file are in the build or bin directory.

Comment: Okay so then where should I be placing the Levels folder and what should the path be? Should I put it within build?

Comment: To keep it simple do this - instead of /Levels - put the full path on the disk for example /user/home/derek/Levels/... See if you can get that to work.

Comment: Awesome - now do this - in your editor check your "build" folder open it and explore it - do you see your text files there?

Comment: No I don't, they aren't there.

Comment: Are you using eclipse? And are the Java and the text files in the same directory called src?

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect, if you are referring to a local file(like something in your project folder) use

```
File file = new File("Levels/level" + (i+1) + ".txt");
```

the slash you used in front of the name makes it look in the root of the drive, not the local directory.